# Make a layout label display an attribute value from a shapefile which overlaps with the center of the layout extent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, layouts

I'm trying to make it so that a layout label always displays the name of the municipality which intersects with the center of the layout map extent.

To do this I've tried using the following expression:

```
aggregate(layer:='Cont_AAD_CAOP2021',
aggregate:='concatenate',expression:="Concelho",
filter:=intersection( geometry(Cont_AAD_CAOP2021),
geometry(item_variables('Map 1')['map_extent_center'])))
```

In which "Cont_AAD_CAOP2021" is the shapefile containing municipality  information, and "Concelho" is a string field containing the municipality names. "Map 1" is the name of the map in the layout.

However, all I get is an empty output, even if the expression gives no error message. I'm guessing the problem is with the filter, but I'm not sure.

I'm using QGIS 3.22.5

EDIT: [The data I'm using and an example project can be found here](https://we.tl/t-9s3DWDEHzB)

Comment: Providing a sample project would help testing

Comment: @Babel Good idea! I've edited the post with a link.

Comment: Sorry: whicht layout do you use in the project you provided?

Comment: Exemplos_OSM 3. I also provided a template layout file in that folder if that doesn't work.

Comment: So you don't use altas function? You manually set the extent of the layout? Why then would you create the municipality name automatically? Seems I don't quite understand your use case. In my solution, I used an atlas with the polygons as coverage layer.

Comment: I just want a text box with the name of the municipality currently in view. A text box is preferable to me, since I can add other information as well. Can the atlas function do that?

Comment: I mean: why don't you simply fill in manually the name of the municipality? If I understood it correctly, you have just one simple layout, not a different layout for every single municipality, right? If not, I didn't understand what you want to do and you should provide a bit more information about your workflow and the final goal you want to achieve: what and how many pages should the layout `Exemplos_OSM 3` finally produce?

Comment: Using atlas function, you can automatically create a separate page, zoomed to the extent of each feature of the coverage layer (e.g. municipalities). But in your case, you just seem to set up a static layout for a fixed extent, so the question arises why not simply add the name manually - using expressions seems like an overkill.

Comment: Because I'm using one layout and editing it as needed. I need several images, and the extent will change as I focus on different polygons. The layer I'm analyizing isn't the Municipalities one, but it provides info I need to present. Instead of manually editing the text box every time I move the extent, it would be done automatically. Maybe a bit overkill to write an expression, but it saves time and I learn a thing or two

Comment: Atlas are a convenient way of generating several images, based on only one layout, for different reference areas (which can be your polygons). Worth the try

Comment: Indeed. You should create a separate (invisible) coverage layer for the layout extents you need and create an atlas. Then you can use the solution I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach is possible, but very inefficient. I would heavily advice to create an atlas (see my other solution). However, just to answer your question and show a way to solve your problem with the approach you tried. There are in fact two problems with what you tried:

- CRS issue
- Wrong syntax.

[image]

#### CRS issue

Use the same CRS for the project and the layer(s) you use to get the intersection. You had `EPSG:32629` as project CRS (used also for your layout), but `EPSG:3763` for the layer `Cont_AAD_CAOP2021`. Reproject the layer to the project CRS, then intersection will work.

#### Expression/syntax

Now use the following expression - see below for explanation:

```
 array_max(
     array_foreach (
         aggregate( 'Cont_AAD_CAOP2021', 'array_agg', $id),
     if(
         intersects (
             map_get (item_variables('Map 1'), 'map_extent_center'),
             geometry (get_feature_by_id ('Cont_AAD_CAOP2021', @element))
         ),
         attribute (
             get_feature_by_id ('Cont_AAD_CAOP2021', @element),
             'Concelho'
         ),
         ''
     )
 ))
```

**Explanation**:

1. The correct syntax to get the center of the current layout page is: `map_get (item_variables ('Map 1'), 'map_extent_center')`, see [`item_variables()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#item-variables) and [`map_get()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#map-get).
2. Instead of aggregate/concatenate the names of the attribute `"Concelho"` and filtering by intersection, rather use [`aggregate/array_agg`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) to get an array of all id's of the layer, then use [`get_feature_by_id ()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#get-feature-by-id) and [`geometry()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id27) to get an array of the geometries from the layer. With [`array-foreach()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-foreach) an an [`if()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#if) clause then test if these geometries intersect with the center of the layout (step 2).
3. For the geometry that returns true (intersects with the center of the current layout), get the value of the field `Concelho` using [`attribute()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#attribute).
4. Use [`array_max()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-max) to get rid of the empty values and keep only the value of the field `Concelho` that indeed intersects the layout's center.

Comment: That was it! I never even thought about the CRS. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Rather then using your approach, which is very inefficients (still, see a solution for that in my other answer), I would heavily advice using the atlas function.

1. Create a new layer called `coverage` with polygons representing the extent of the layouts you want (see screenshot at the bottom). When you set up the atlas, QGIS will automatically generate a layout for each polygon with the extent of this polygon - this is a very handy way to get a separate page for different areas of interest and still keep the same layout settings, but with dynamic parameters that respect the current extent for each layout sheet.
2. In your layout, go to the tab <kbd>Atlas</kbd> check the box <kbd>Generate an atlas</kbd> and select the layer created in step 1 as Coverage layer.

   [image]
3. Got to <kbd>Item Properties</kbd> of your map and check the box <kbd>Controlled by Atlas</kbd>.
   [image]
4. Now go to your text field and use this expression:

   ```
    attribute (
        get_feature_by_id(
            'Cont_AAD_CAOP2021',
            overlay_intersects ('Cont_AAD_CAOP2021', $id, sort_by_intersection_size:='des')[0]
        ),
        'Concelho'
    )
   ```

[image]

*Coverage layer with polygons in pink, the one highlighted in yellow is the one producing the layout above:*
[image]

Comment: I didn't have your project. I have now updated the solution based on the project you provided.